# Unexpected behavior referencing object-groups in access-lists on Catalyst 4500

Tags: cisco-catalyst, acl

I'm encountering some unexpected behavior when trying to reference object-groups in an access-list on my Catalyst 4500.

**Goal:** Restrict a VLAN from accessing other privately addressed subnets (Internet access only), except for a local DNS server in another subnet

**IOS-XE Version:** 03.03.00.XO RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)

**General Config:**

```
object-group network subnet_privateClassA 
 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0
!
object-group network subnet_privateClassB 
 172.16.0.0 255.240.0.0
!
object-group network subnet_privateClassC 
 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0
!
object-group network subnet_rfc1918All 
 group-object subnet_privateClassA
 group-object subnet_privateClassB
 group-object subnet_privateClassC
!
!

...

interface Vlan70
 ip address 10.10.70.254 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group publicVlan_in in
!
```

The following access-list blocks access to private IP ranges, except for the desired DNS server (10.16.4.10), but also blocks access to public IPs. So, DNS is able resolve google.com, but pings fail.

```
ip access-list extended publicVlan_in
 permit ip any host 10.32.4.10
 deny ip any object-group subnet_rfc1918All ! (I've also tried just subnet_privateClassA)
 permit ip any any
!
```

The next access list works exactly how I want - local DNS works and I can access the Internet:

```
ip access-list extended publicVlan_in
 permit ip any host 10.32.4.10
 deny   ip any 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
 deny   ip any 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255
 deny   ip any 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255
 permit ip any any
!
```

The problem seems to be the use of object-groups. What am I missing here?

Comment: I suspect a typo.  Can you post the actual config?

Comment: `show ip access-group publicVlan_in` for both versions of the ACL

Comment: @Ron, I've updated my post with a copy/paste from my config.

Comment: @RickyBeam - That access list is in production temporarily, so I can't update it to the non-working configuration just now. I did however examine the output of `show ip access-list publicVlan_in` (I'm assuming that's what you mean) while troubleshooting originally. I used pings to generate traffic, but the entry referencing the object-group didn't seem to be incrementing proportionally. I'm not sure what that means...

Comment: If it doesn't appear to be automatically incrementing properly when using the object-group access list, have you tried manually incrementing each rule (10, 20, 30, etc) and then applying the newly created list?

Comment: A good thought, but the number was incremented properly.

Comment: Do object-groups need to use the wildcard mask vs the standard mask?

Comment: You have to use the show command to indicate the line numbers in IOS/IOS-XE...

Comment: No, object-groups use the standard mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At long last, an answer. I recently encountered another situation where I had to create access-lists that would benefit from object-group references. After trying several different things to work around the problem, I finally threw in the towel and contacted Cisco technical support (which I'm always loath to do).

After an initial careless and blatantly wrong attempt to answer my question, the Cisco technician came back with the following:

> Matthew,
>
> I have reached out to the development team and object group
>   configuration with the 4500 platform does not work as desired given
>   the fact that the feature is not fully supported until code version
>   15.2(3)E2 which will be released around August 2015.
>
> It is possible for the ACL to be configured because they have the same
>   IOS XE base as other devices that support the feature at this time.

So, there you go - and it only took Cisco 6 days to come up with this answer (a record).

Answer (score -3):

Use a policy routing instead.  Two line to ACL deny any to inside DNS server then allow all else inside.  Set the next hop to the ISP interface's IP address.

Example:

`Router(config-route-map)# set ip next-hop ip-address [ip-address]`

Specifies the next hop to which the packet will be routed, and the next hop must be an adjacent interface of the next router.